# Sending email with attachment in ASP.NET C# web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a web application with contact us page in that i am having field like 
Name:
email address:
phone number :
Attach file :
Message:
Send button

Now on send button click, i want to send the email to some abc@gmail.com with the above body content.

to do some what code i need to write in .cs file

this is what i have tried

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");

            mail.Body = "<b> Sender Name : </b>" + txtbname.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<b> Sender Email : </b>" + txtbemail.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<b> Sender Contact Number : </b>" + txtphone.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<b> Message : </b>" + txtbmessage.Text;

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("Attachment" + this.fp);

            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


            smtpServer.Port = 587;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "password");

            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            smtpServer.Send(mail);

            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            label1.Text = "SENT";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        label1.Text = "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work without attachment?  What version of Net are you using?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: No i wont work either

Comment: Midhun Mundayadan When i remove try block following error                                                       The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: Yes this error is because you have to  Allow less secure apps from your gmail account

Answer (score 2):

For sending mail you have to Allow less secure apps from your gmail account

1. Login with your gmail account and find "Allow less secure apps:" [from here](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#activity).
2. Google manages security with your gmail account. You need to turn on "Allow less secure apps:" and you will receive mail in your gmail account.